# DEM polygonize (raster to vector) doesn't work for contour lines less than 1 meter apart? (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, contour, polygonize

I tried to make polygon from DEM (geotiff) in QGIS. My requirement is that elevation value was every 0.5m of polygon. If I use the function  polygonize (raster to vector)  , polygon is created but only 1 meter elevation value. It's possible created this polygon with 0.5m elevation value please?

Answer (score 2):

Although there is a float version available in gdal as a function, the `gdal_polygonize` python script uses the integer version of this function, as ahmadhanb stated.

This might be a way to work around this.

- First, use raster calculator to double your elevations (`raster_layer@1 * 2`, for example) and write this to a new raster. Use `1/interval` to multiply, so 0.25m bands would use x4, 0.2m bands x5 and so on.
- Run polygonize on the new raster (from QGIS). This should give you polygons representing 0.5m bands, but the DN values will be 2x what they should be.
- Add a real field to your polygonal layer and use the expression calculator to halve the values e.g. `to_real("DN")/2.0`.

Comment: It is unusual but effective solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: That was an awesome answer Steven!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you would be able to create a polygon elevation with 0.5m interval directly by converting the DEM to polygon. The DEM has a type of float, and when you convert the DEM to polygon you will convert the pixel value to integer which means you will not get fractions like 0.5. In order to get the attribute table of a raster, the pixel values or DN values of the DEM will be converted to integer first, then the polygons with elevation values will be written to the attribute table.

However, there is a tool under processing toolbox `Grass -> Raster -> r.contour.step - Create vector contours from raster at specified steps`, there is an advance option in which you can specify to get the output as area or region, but I doubt it will give you the desired results. You will end up with dirty polygons that need long time to clean them. But you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could to use "gdal_contour".

This tool is in Menu of QGIS >> Raster >> Extraction >> Contour...

- Input raster = your DEM
- Interval between contour line = 0.5 (metres)